# Change link of clicked item in div with id - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the link in my div which has `<div id="0">` .

My `div` code:

```
    <div id="0">
   <div id="header_color" class="spacing-top context_menu">
      <div class="row">
         <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 heading-sm28">Lets get started on project.</div>
         <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 smalltxt-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the test change link.</div>
         <div class="col-md-12 center context_menu context_link"><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="btntst-back">Get in touch</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 heading-sm28">Lets get started on project.</div>
         <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 smalltxt-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the test change link.</div>
         <div class="col-md-12 center context_menu context_link"><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="btntst-back">Get in touch</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The command I am trying to use is -

```
$(id).children().attr("href",'http://example.com');
```

Value of **id** I am getting is -

```
var id = '#'+this.selectedDivCodesub+' '+".clickedDiv";
```

which is - `#0 .clickedDiv`

I am sure I am doing something wrong while **getting the `id`**. Note that I am using clickedDiv because I am trying to change the address of the clicked link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Why do you need to change the link? This smells like an [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem](XY problem).

Comment: where are you adding `clickedDiv` class and at what event?

Comment: Looking for paid jquery support, please mail at ersaurabh101@gmail.com

Comment: Your selector mentions the class `.clickedDiv` but your HTML doesn't contain that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but you can try :)

```
$(function(){
$('#0').click(function(){
$('.center context_menu context_link').attr("href",'http://example.com');
})
});
```

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the Id of the element you are appending a **className** to the Id which doesn't make sense as:

```
var id = '#'+this.selectedDivCodesub+' '+".clickedDiv";
```

the above code returns you the selector to pick the div and there is no such div with a class `clickedDiv`

what you need to do is, give your div a class (all the divs that may have that child) and bind a click event to it like:

```
<div id="0" class="someClassName">
```

and in your JS just attach a click event to the clicked element and add a class to the clicked element (only if there is a real need)

```
$( ".someClassName" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).addClass("clicked");
  $(this).children().attr("href",'http://example.com'); //not a good idea but your requirement states it

});
```

Comment: i will try this and vote, meanwhile i am looking for paid jquery support for my cms workif you have time then please ping me here - ersaurabh101@gmail.com